# Magento 2 Get product collection in a custom template block

Tags: magento2, template, collection, model, product-collection

I have defined a featured product template in a cms static page as below:

```
{{block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" template="Magento_Catalog::product/featured.phtml"}}
```

Now I want to load original product collection(without any filters applied, which I am gonna apply later) inside my template `"featured.phtml"`, but I can't find a way to do it directly without creating a module for such a tiny task.

Somebody let me know, how to do something like below in Magento2, in this case: `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()`

Comment: Have you tried `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct::getLoadedProductCollection`? It is accessible in your template just as `$this->getLoadedProductCollection()`.

Comment: Yes tried that already, but it is already a filtered collection with very less products, I need raw colleciton without any filters like `$this->getCollection()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is better to create custom block for your needs. It is not clear why you can create custom template, but not block. Also have you considered using `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface::getList` which is part of Magento public API? Collection should not be manipulated directly.

Implementation below is a hack (object manager should never be used directly), but the only solution without creation of a new block:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productCollection */
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
/** Apply filters here */
$productCollection->load();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, can you tell me how to filter this collection by `category_id`, I tried filtering using function `addFieldToFilter` but it gives error, I guess `addField....` function only works for table's own fields not with joining tables.

Comment: `$productCollection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => [1, 2, 3]])` should work.

Comment: Thanks, your solution is working perfectly for now. Accepting it.

Comment: @AlexPaliarush How do i use filter by attribute and select attribute like name, id, v.v.. via ProductRepository
example:$this->_productRepository->getList($this->_searchCriteria)->addAttributeToFilter('is_featured', 1)
results undefined method trigger

Comment: @mrtuvn `$this->_searchCriteria` should contain necessary filters. `addAttributeToFilter` is defined for collections and is not available for repositories. Take a look at [these answers](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search-criteria)

Answer (score 9):

Instead of using the Object manager u can try:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,        
    array $data = []
)
{    
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

 public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->setPageSize(3); // fetching only 3 products
    return $collection;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In your block file:

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

protected $_productFactory;

public function __construct(
   Context $context, 
   ProductFactory $productFactory,
   array $data = array()       
) {
   $this->_productFactory   = $productFactory;
   parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getProductCollection() {
   $productCollection = $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection();
   return $productCollection;
}
```

To get the collection call `getProductCollection` function.

Comment: product Factory is used to create new product, don't use it that way

Comment: you can check the default magento 2 files it uses product factory.

Comment: you should use CollectionFactory instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($data);
    }



    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        /** @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        return $collection;
    }
```

Comment: Not working in Magento 2 stable version.

Comment: updated ans pls check

Comment: I know that by overriding the Block(probably in our own module) it can be done, but I am asking for doing this without module way as I mentioned in my question.